# Parallel execution sequence

Tags: oracle, performance, execution-plan, oracle-12c

[image: SQL Statement and Paln]

Which statement is correct about the parallel executions plan?

- A. The CUSTOMERS and SALES tables are scanned simultaneously in parallel and then joined in parallel.
- B. First, the CUSTOMERS table is scanned in parallel, then the SALES table is scanned in parallel, and then they are joined serially.
- C. First, the SALES table is scanned in parallel, then the CUSTOMERS table us scanned in parallel, and then they are joined in parallel.
- D. The CUSTOMERS and SALES tables are scanned simultaneously in parallel and thenjoined serially.
- E. First, the CUSTOMERS table is scanned in parallel, then the SALES table us scanned in parallel, and then they are joined in parallel.

I think E is correct but the correct answer is A. Why?

Comment: Who told you that the correct answer is option `A`? Don't rely upon answers provided on some random blogs, try to understand how to read execution plan. Better explanation is here in Oracle's official documentation. [How Parallel Execution Works](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)

Comment: @JSapkota I think the answer is E. The answer provided is not correct.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://oracle-randolf.blogspot.de/2017/01/oracle-parallel-execution-deep-dive.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I finish the video. very useful. this plan just have one DFO tree.  I think my thinking is correct. E is correct.

Comment: You removed the indention of the plan steps which is an essential part of the plan from the screen shot so this is hard to tell. But I would think that it's A as well (if the tables are big enough, you _could_ verify that through `v$session_longops`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But the video said that ONE DFO tree have one pair active producer and consumer. If two tables can scan simultaneously, who is consumer??

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your provided method. however, this is a test answer. I do not have real data to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B, D incorrect:

The join is performed in parallel, there is only 1 serial operation on the picture, only one parallel->serial (P->S) transition, and that is when the query coordinator collects the results.

A (, D) incorrect:

Parallel SQL uses the producer-consumer model. One set reads the table, the other set builds/probes the hash table, they do not read seperate tables simultaneously.

C incorrect:

There is only 1 DFO (`:TQ1`), the order of execution can be easily recognized by the order of virtual tables or the table queues (`:TQ1000x`). This is not necessarily true for multiple DFOs, but it is inside 1 DFO. `:TQ10000` comes before `:TQ10001`, but `:TQ10000` does not necessarily come before `:TQ20000`. Read more about this:

https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2015/12/21/parallel-plans-2/

So the first table to be read is `CUSTOMER`, not `SALES`.

E correct:

Well, this is how it works, but that is not a real explanation. Easier to prove the other options wrong.